# When assembly is inside 'C:\Windows\System32' i get 'Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application'

Tags: c#, .net, screensaver

I'm currently writing a screensaver using C# and the express version of VS2010. I've created a nice little screensaver and renamed the resulting assembly to have a *.scr extension.

When i place this on my desktop and double click it (or select configure from the context menu), it runs fine and displays the correct form/screensaver. However, when i *install* this by placing it into the `C:\Windows\System32` folder, i try double clicking on it and get this error:

`Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application`

Also it doesn't work from the screensaver control panel. It's listed in the drop-down but it doesn't function.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Don't copy assemblies into this private Windows directory.  It is redirected on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: That's probably it! What do you mean by redirected though? And how would i install a screensaver if not into the 'system32' dir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the screensaver was compiled for 32bit cpu. Only 64bit exes are allowed in the `%WINDIR%\System32` folder on a 64bit OS. Which in fact, i was using Windows7 64bit.

The correct place to put 32bit screensavers is in `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64` or compile using 'AnyCPU' option in Visual Studio then you can install into the `%WINDIR%\System32` for all.